# parallelization several for loops in julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have several loops like:

```
for i = 1 : m
        var1 = 1
        var2 = 12.4
        for j = 1 : n
            var3=8
            var4=array1[1]
                for l = var1 : n
                    var5 = aary1[l]
                    var6 = arry2[l,i]+var5
                    if var6 > var3
                        var7 = var6
                        var8 = array1[l]
                        var1 = l
                    else
                        break
                    end

                end
                array3[j,i] = var7
                array4[j,i] = var8
                println("........")
          end
    end
```

I want to parallel this code by static scheduling ( @parallel for). How can I Parallel these loops?

Comment: Just put `@parallel` in front of the `for` and make sure you run it with some processes setup (`addprocs()`). Is that the question?

Comment: Is it enough for parallelization several loops?

Comment: You only put `@parallel` on the outer loop, then let the inner loops be the full routine on a given process. You want to parallelize "as high up" as you can to decrease the overhead of parallelism.

Comment: m is 4 and n is 20000, is it good if i put parallel in outer loop?

Comment: I put parallel on the outer loop and the result is not correct!